# How to use Pandas calculate # of weeks/days?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

[image]

Hi, I have a dataframe with date columns. I want to add a column to calculate how many weeks since the contact? For example, today's date is 20-Sep-18, and use this date to calculate with the column.

Can anyone help me with this questions? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! this helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
    df['Contact Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Contact Date'])
    import datetime
    df['How Many days'] =  datetime.datetime.now() - df['Contact Date']
```